# How to use checked input values used for math as part of cloned div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a script that clones a certain div as required by the user. Within the div there are three checkbox input options and each option as a numeric value. I want the script to allow the user to select a checkbox and then the value will be reflected in another input space and each value that are added will be separated by a comma.

The tricky part is that it should be done for each clone, and that each checkbox has the same class name to which the script should be written. I realize that using unique id's would be better, but I would like it that a for loop could do it for any number of checkboxes under the specific class.

Here is the html script:

```
<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<body>
    <h2>Test</h2>

    <button id="add">Add</button>

    <div class="test hidden">       

        <div class="user_input1">
            <label>Input1</label>
            <input class="input1" type="text" required>
            <label>Input2</label>
            <input type="text" name="value2" required>

            <div class="user_input2">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Pick Option</th>                    
                        </tr>                                   
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>    
                        <tr id="append"> 
                            <td><input class="test" type="checkbox" name="test" value="1">Test1</td>  
                            <td><input class="test" type="checkbox" name="test" value="2">Test2</td> 
                            <td><input class="test" type="checkbox" name="test" value="3">Test3</td>            
                        </tr>     
                    </tbody>
                </table>    
                <input type="text" id="insert" name="check">
                <button class="hidden" id="testbtn">Calc</button>   
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <form action="server/server.php" method="POST">
        <div class="paste">     
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="insert_res">Submit</button>
    </form> 
</body>
```

And my attempt for the jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var variable = 0
        $("#add").click(function() {
            var element = $(".test.hidden").clone(true);
            element.removeClass("hidden").appendTo(".paste:last");

        });     


    });

    $(document).ready(function(event) {

        $(".test").keyup(function(){
            if ($(".test").is(":checked")) {

                var test = $(".test").val();                    
            };

            $("#insert").val(test);

        });

        $("#testbtn").click(function() {
            $(".test").keyup();
        });

    });
```

I think a for loop should be used for each checkbox element and `this` to specify each individual clone, but I have no idea where or how to do this. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you already know how to get a reference to the dom element you need in order to append, as well as how to create elements and append them.

You are right in that you can loop over your dataset and produce dom elements with unique id's so you can later refer to them when transferring new values into your input.

```
...forEach((obj, index) => {
  (produce tr dom element here)
  (produce three inputs, give all unique-identifier)
  oneOfThreeInputs.setAttribute('unique-identifier', index); // can set to whatever you want, really
  (proceed to creating your inputs and appending them to the tr dom element)
  targetInputDomElementChild.setAttribute('id', `unique-input-${index}`); // same here, doesn't have to be class
});
```

Observe that I am using template strings to concat the index number value to the rest of the strings. From then on, you can either reference the index to refer to the correct input or tr using jquery in your keyUp event handler:

```
function keyUpEventHandler($event) {
  const index = $(this).attr('unique-identifier');

  const targetInput = $(`#unique-input-${index}`)

  // do stuff with targetInput
}
```

I have created a fiddle to show you the route you can take using the above information:

http://jsfiddle.net/zApv4/48/

Notice that when you click an checkbox, in the console you will see the variable number that designates that set of checkboxes. You can use that specific number to get the input you need to add to and concat the values.

Of course, you still need to validate whether it is being checked or unchecked to you can remove from the input.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but would you mind elaborating a little bit more. I am afraid you lost me in that I fail to the the connection to my own script. Which part of mine should be interchanged and so on...

Comment: I believe you will have a lot to change. The thing is, it seems like you are putting the keyup event on the wrapper div, but I don't believe that will work if you intent is to add the value of the selected input to another input in 'val1, val2, val3' fashion. Seems to me each of your inputs will need a click event handler assigned to them to make it work.

Comment: Updated my answer with a fiddle to get you on the right track.

Comment: That works nicely thank you, but if you uncheck a option it also appends a value?

Comment: Yes, like I said, you simply need to check if the checkbox is check or unchecked, and instead of performing the 'combo' logic, you'll have to splice out that portion of the string and assign it in the same way.

Comment: Very good, I will try to analyse and understand what you did. Thank you so much for your help!